# Wordpress echo/print_r function causing image upload issue or showing media grid

Tags: wordpress, image, echo, media

If I call a simple function that contains echo/print/print_r will cause 2 issues:
1) Uploading media doesn't show that the image is uploaded but it does upload the image.

2) If I view the images in media in Grid mode then it doesn't show the images and keep loading but if I click List view then it shows the images.

Example function in functions.php file:

```
function test() {
    echo 'test test test test test test test test test';
}
test();
```

The above function does print the text 'test test..' but the above 2 issues occur and as soon as I comment test(); then everything works fine. Completely blank them and I am not using any plugins. I need to use echo for some of the functions to show some data.

thanks

Comment: Is the function `test();` called in functions.php itself or in template files like page.php , inde.php etc ?

Comment: If you change your theme to twentyseventeen and check uploading images and viewing images in grid mode will work fine and then just paste the following code in the end of twentyseventeen/functions.php file and check again the image issues start:

function test() {
    echo 'test test test test test test test test test';
}
test();